# I am installing jenkins server but its giving W: GPG error:

Tags: 14.04

Hello all i am installing Jenkins server but i am facing below issue.

W: GPG error: http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org binary/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9B7D32F2D50582E6

Please Help

I run this command gpg --import KEYS but it returns

gpg: can't open `KEYS': No such file or directory
gpg: Total number processed: 0

I am using proxy for open internet.

Answer (score 11):

I myself had the same issue. After adding the Google keys from the official web [repository](https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/), it worked.

Google helped with the following command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <the key>
```

In this case:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 9B7D32F2D50582E6
```

Comment: That helped, tks a lot

Answer (score 7):

i think you are doing mistake to add gpg key. add key using command

```
wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

and add repository

```
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
```

update source list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install jenkins

```
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

if you already downloaded gpg key then add key using command

```
sudo apt-key add  jenkins-ci.org.key
```

Comment: this worked: `deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian-stable binary/`

Answer (score 6):

This means key from jenkins site is not properly added.

1. Run

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

In the end you would get output like

```
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN                 
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_IN           
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_IN           
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IN             
Fetched 181 B in 25s (7 B/s)                                                   
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org binary/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY < ???? >
```

???? - would be the key for you.

2. Now use this key in the command below

   ```
   sudo gpg --keyserver  http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key --recv-keys ????
   ```

you would get response as

```
gpg: requesting key D50582E6 from http server pkg.jenkins-ci.org
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key D50582E6: public key "Kohsuke Kawaguchi <kk@kohsuke.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

3. Add to the sources using command.

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
   ```
4. Now you can install using

   ```
   sudo apt-get install jenkins
   ```